# How to represent binary relations?

Tags: logic, relations

Basically, Im not sure how to to evaluate if a ∧ b is a function, injective, reflexive etc. I can evaluate these properties if Its a real function e.g. f(x) = x+2 as I can just look at the graph/test these properties using numbers. But I have no idea how to represent "a ∧ b" as a graph/in a relationship diagram. To reiterate, I understand the definitions of injective, reflexive etc, I just dont know how to apply them to binary relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $\;\;\text{graph} \;(C) = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z\mid C(a, b) = T\},\;$ where the binary relation is $"\land$" $\;$ and so $aCb \iff a\land b = T$

$ (T\land T) = T, \quad (T \land F) =  F, \quad (F\land T) = F$,  $  (F\land F) = F $

So $C = \{(T,T)\}$

Note that the relation $\text{graph}C = \{(a, b)= (T, T)\}$, (because $a\land b$ is true only when $a =b= T$.  Clearly, Since we need a = b = T, $a C a =T$, and $b C b = T$.  So the relation is reflexive. It is also symmetric, since $(a, b) = (T, T) = (b, a)$

Comment: I tried to use the notation you used in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the problem. You can view $\wedge$ as function
$$
\wedge : \{0,1\}^2 \to \{0,1\}
$$
and verify it is a function (it is single valued at each point). It is not injective, as 
$$
\wedge(t,f) = \wedge(f,t) = f
$$
so several arguments point to the same value.

To see if it is reflexive, you have to view it as relation:
$$
\wedge(t,t) = t \iff t \wedge t \\
\wedge(f,f) = f \iff \neg (f \wedge f)
$$
so it is not reflexive. Etc. A table could be:
$$
\begin{array}{r|rr}
x \wedge y & f & t \\
\hline
f &  - & - \\
t &  - & \surd
\end{array}
$$

Comment: The OP is struggling with the binary operation $\land$", as in  $\;\;a \land b$